# React componentDidMount() initializing state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

Working on a small project in React, and I'm using Axios to grab information from an API that is tested working. The problem is when I pull in the data and try to update the component state, the values coming in from the API aren't getting filled into the state to be rendered in the component.

I've been trying to get the data in the state like so:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.databases.forEach(d => {
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3204/customer/${d}/count`).then(value => {
        this.setState({ counts: this.state.counts.push(value.data) });
      });
    });
    console.log(this.state);
  }
```

a previous version was written like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let internalCounts = [];
    this.state.databases.forEach(d => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3204/customer/${d}/count`).then(value => {
            internalCounts.push(value.data);
        });
    });
    this.setState({count: internalCounts});
}
```

Both situations end up with the same result. The state is never really updated with the new count array. I have the suspicion that this is due to the async nature of `Axios` **and** `setState`.

What would be a simple, effective way to get these two to stop racing each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `console.log` immediately after setting the state since it is asynchronous. Do it with a callback to `setState`.

```
this.setState({...}, () => console.log(...))
```

or inspect your state in your render method with `console.log`

Also, rather than doing it `forEach`, try to make all the request in one time with `Promise.all` if this suits you.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const promiseArray = this.state.databases.map( d =>
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3204/${d}/count`)
    )
    Promise.all( promiseArray )
      .then( ( results ) => {
        const data = results.map( result => result.data);
        this.setState( prevState => ({
          counts: [ ...prevState.counts, ...data]
        }))
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first version you are correct that it is due to the async nature of the service. You are logging the output, but this is happening before the service has resolved.

In the second (previous) example you are setting the state before it resolves. I would recommend the following approach, creating an array of the promises then waiting for all of them to resolve before you update state:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const promises = [];
    this.state.databases.forEach(d => {
        promises.push(axios.get(`http://localhost:3204/customer/${d}/count`));
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
        const internalCounts = [];
        results.map(result => {
            internalCounts.push(result.data);
        });
        this.setState({count: internalCounts});
    })
}
```

Comment: By the way, I would recommend using the React Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools), it enables you to inspect state and props realtime and makes debugging things like this much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The issues was I was attempting to mutate state. (I've been horrible with immutable data.... so something I'll have to get used to.)

My solution code is as follows:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.state.databases.forEach(d => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3204/${d}/count`).then(value => {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                counts: [...prevState.counts, value.data]
            }));
         });
    });
}
```

Comment: I prefer the approach above because its only setting state one time so you are avoiding multiple re renders.

Comment: that makes sense. However, the data structure of the counts has changed, I moved over to an object, and am iterating over the object keys to ensure the correct data is displayed with the correct header. @ForrestLyman, mind if we chat about this outside the question? I have it working, but I'd like to refactor to only update the state once.

Comment: Definitely. You can hit me up at forrestswork@gmail.com or on LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems with your code:

1. `Array.prototype.push(value.data)` returns the new length, not the new array. So `this.setState({ counts: this.state.counts.push(value.data) });` is making `state.counts` into a number value `this.state.counts.length + 1`, which is probably not desired.
2. If you want to print out the new state, the `console.log(this.state);` should be put into the callback param of `setState()`.
3. Your previous version did not await for the axios call before `setState`. You got the idea right.